# svg cursor pointer missing between two sub-component

Tags: svg

```css
@namespace svgns url(http://www.w3.org/2000/svg);
html,body,svg { height:100% }/* As SVG does not provide a default visual style for links,
   it's considered best practice to add some */

@namespace svgns url(http://www.w3.org/2000/svg);

svgns|a {
  cursor: pointer;
}

svgns|a text {
  fill: blue; /* Even for text, SVG use fill over color */
  text-decoration: underline;
}

svgns|a:hover, svgns|a:active {
  outline: dotted 1px blue;
}
```

```html
<!-- Learn about this code on MDN: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/a -->

<svg viewBox="0 0 100 100" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
  

  <!-- A link around a text -->
  <a href="https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/SVG/Element/circle">
  <g style="cursor: pointer">
    <image xlink:href="https://mdn.mozillademos.org/files/6457/mdn_logo_only_color.png" height="50" width="50"/>
    <text x="50" y="90" text-anchor="middle">
      &lt;circle&gt;
    </text>
    </g>
  </a>
</svg>
```

I have an SVG, it contains animage as well as text. the SVGhas style `{ cursor: pointer}`.
When I hover on the image, I can have cursor pointer, same to the text. But if I hover on that space between the image and text, I lose the "hand". 
Is there any way I can have it?

Thanks for the help.

[example](https://jsfiddle.net/du1qg046/)

```
enter code here
```

Comment: You can add `cursor: pointer` to entire `svg` element if you do not have any other elements in svg.

Answer (score 1):

You can apply `cursor: pointer` to entire `svg` element if this is all content you have in `svg`. 
Otherwise, you can add a simple `rect` before the `image`:

```
<rect x="0" y="0" width="100" height="100" fill="transparent" />
```

As the `g` element can't be styled directly, as styles apply to nested elements only, but `rect` can be (and as a nested element of `g` as well).

```css
@namespace svgns url(http://www.w3.org/2000/svg);
html,
body,
svg {
  height: 100%
}


/* As SVG does not provide a default visual style for links,
   it's considered best practice to add some */

svgns|a {
  cursor: pointer;
}

svgns|a text {
  fill: blue;
  /* Even for text, SVG use fill over color */
  text-decoration: underline;
}

svgns|a:hover,
svgns|a:active {
  outline: dotted 1px blue;
}
```

```html
<!-- Learn about this code on MDN: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/a -->

<svg viewBox="0 0 100 100" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
  

  <!-- A link around a text -->
  <a href="https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/SVG/Element/circle">
    <rect x="0" y="0" width="100" height="100" fill="transparent" />
    <image xlink:href="https://mdn.mozillademos.org/files/6457/mdn_logo_only_color.png" height="50" width="50"/>
    <text x="50" y="90" text-anchor="middle">
      &lt;circle&gt;
    </text>
  </a>
</svg>
```